# Which of the following figures represents the relationship between english teachers, popular english teachers and unpopular teachers?

Tags: logic

I am not sure if this is the right platform for this question but In India, we have a PSA test which is based on logic and I have a question which I cannot understand, so the question is:-

Which of the following figures represents the relationship between english teachers, popular english teachers and unpopular teachers?(with the diagram)
[image: This is the diagram]

The answer is (b) as given in the book but it doesn't explain why? So could someone give me the explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Popular English teachers are a subset of the set of English teachers. So the oval for popular English will have to be inside the oval for English. Thus the only candidates are b) and d). Now think about why d) is not right, but b) is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is (b) because you can be for being a popular English teacher, you have to be an English teacher. Similarly, unpopular teachers can be English teachers too (but never popular English teachers!).

If you still need some formalism, let:

- *A* denotes the set of English teachers
- *B* denotes the set of popular English teachers
- *C* denotes the set of unpopular teachers

Then $B \subseteq A$ and $B \cap C = \emptyset$.

But since as far as we know nothing is said that $A \cap C = \emptyset$ too, we chose (b).